# DateFormat in Tooltip for Scatter Plot does not change

Tags: highcharts, flask

I am integrating my flask app with Highcharts and the Highcharts graph is a blend of two lines (one which is a spline and the other is a scatterplot). The line shows the correct date format in the tooltip whereas the scatter plot does not.

I did see a link where this can be done by writing JavaScript code:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %Y, %H:00', this.x) + '</b> ' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' m/s';
    }
}
```

I want to do this without writing JavaScript code.

My main python code is like this:

```
series = [
    {
        "type":"scatter",
        "name": 'Data Points',
        "data":modified_result,
        "tooltip":{"xDateFormat":'%Y-%m-%d'}
    },
    {
        "type":"spline",
        "name": 'trend line',
        "data":line_result,
        "tooltip":{"xDateFormat":'%Y-%m-%d'}
    }
]
```

and then I render my template by saying:

```
return flask.render_template('index.html',
           result = result,
           predicted_prices = predicted_prices,
           chartID=chartID,
           chart=chart,
           series=series,
           title=title,
           xAxis=xAxis,
           yAxis=yAxis)
```

and in index.html, I have:

```
<script>
  var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}
  var series = {{ series|safe }}
  var title = {{ title|safe }}
  var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
  var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
  var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
```

Which calls the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(chart_id).highcharts({
    chart: chart,
    title: title,
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    series: series
  });
});
```

Comment: How would you do this without javascript code? What is your current tooltip format and what is the format you are expecting? What does your code look like for the chart?

Comment: I have changed my original question to include how I am doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'scatter' type has a little bit different setup for the tooltip. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198989/33727). You can do this in your `series` setup code like you do already for `xDateFormat`.

```
{
    "type":"scatter",
    "name": 'Data Points',
    "data":modified_result,
    "tooltip":{
       "xDateFormat":'%Y-%m-%d',
       "headerFormat": '{point.key}<br />',
       "pointFormat": '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
    }
}
```

You can play around inside of here to set it up more finely to how you want it.
Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/k2uy7bfy/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured out how to do this so that it does not effect the date format.

Instead of using:

```
series = [
{
    "type":"scatter",
    "name": 'Data Points',
    "data":modified_result,
    "tooltip":{"xDateFormat":'%Y-%m-%d'}
}
```

I reformatted that as:

```
series = [{"name": 'Data Points', "data":modified_result, "marker" : { \
                "enabled" : "true", \
                "radius" : 4 \
            },"lineWidth" : 0,}
```

This would show a scatter plot with the right date format.